# html being processed in string_replace as variable

Tags: php, variables, replace

I have a html `<h1 class="title">[VALUE]</h1>` where `[VALUE]` gets replaced with some data when the template is processed.

I would like to used the data that replaces `[VALUE]` in a php variable.

Something like this,
`$my_var = '[VALUE]';`
but the above don't work.

```
function getHTML($articleid, $fieldid, $category = false, $write=false)
    { 
        global $globalreturn;

      //$str = fieldattach::getInput($articleid, $fieldid, $category); 
      $html ='';
      $valor = fieldattach::getValue( $articleid,  $fieldid , $category   );
      $title = fieldattach::getName( $articleid,  $fieldid , $category  );
      $published = plgfieldsattachment_input::getPublished( $fieldid  );


      if(!empty($valor) && $published)
      {


          $html = plgfieldsattachment_input::getTemplate($fieldid);

          if(fieldattach::getShowTitle(   $fieldid  )) $html = str_replace("[TITLE]", $title, $html); 
          else 
          $html = str_replace("[TITLE]", "", $html); 
          $html = str_replace("[VALUE]", $valor, $html);
          $html = str_replace("[FIELD_ID]", $fieldid, $html);
      }


       //WRITE THE RESULT
       if($write)
       {
            echo $html;
       }else{
            $globalreturn = $html;
            return $html; 
       }
    }

    function getTemplate($fieldsids, $file="input", $valor)
    {
        global $globalreturn;
        echo $valor;


          $templateDir =  dirname(__FILE__).'/tmpl/'.$file.'.tpl.php'; 
          $html = file_get_contents ($templateDir);


          $app = JFactory::getApplication();
          $templateDir =  JPATH_BASE . '/templates/' . $app->getTemplate().'/html/com_fieldsattach/fields/'.$file.'.tpl.php';

          if(file_exists($templateDir))
          {

              $html = file_get_contents ($templateDir);
          }

          $app = JFactory::getApplication();
          $templateDir =  JPATH_BASE . '/templates/' . $app->getTemplate().'/html/com_fieldsattach/fields/'.$fieldsids.'_'.$file.'.tpl.php';

          if(file_exists($templateDir))
          { 

              include ($templateDir);
          }

          //return $html;
    }
```

I am trying to use the $valor form function getHTML(); inside the getTemplate();
As you will see in he code above I already tried to call global $globalreturn and then echo $valor; but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows

I think you want pass variable to another page. So add following code in myfile.php

```
  <h1 class="title"><?php define ( 'myVariable', '[VALUE]' ); ?></h1>
```

And call using require function in your next page.

```
<?php
require("myfile.php");
?>
```

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. let me try reformulate my question. How do I use php tags in a php file that is being called unsing file_get_content('myfile.php');

Comment: Add <?php
define ( 'myVariable', '[VALUE]' );
?>    and call using require("myfile.php");

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work. I decided to just create class variables and call them on my file. Initially my goal was to not change this extension core files but I already spent too much time on it. :) if i call the file using require it displays the number 1, not the value.

Comment: Please not use $ sign in define function. Just use myVariable.  Like echo myVariable;

Comment: Hi Arshid Kv, i just tried that again. still no lucky. I did as you suggested. I loaded my file using 'require' and <h1><?php define ($html, '[VALUE]');?></h1>

Comment: No need $ sign in this case. Please read http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_define.asp

Comment: Just use <h1><?php define ('html', '[VALUE]');?></h1>       Then require('myfile.php')  , just check <?php echo html; ?> you can see [VALUE] will print.